# Is $\frac{-\sqrt{1-|a-\lambda b|^2}+\sqrt{1-|a|^2}}{\lambda |b|} |b|$ related in some way with first derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, vectors

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be two nonnull vectors with $|a|\le 1$. Let $\lambda>0$.
I have this quantity
$$\frac{-\sqrt{1-|a-\lambda b|^2}+\sqrt{1-|a|^2}}{-\lambda |b|} |b|$$
which I am trying to "simplify", to manage.

As $\lambda\to 0$, it seems to me something related with the definition of first derivative.

Actually, I am not convinced about that essentially for 2 reasons:

1. $a$ and $b$ are vectors;
2. I am not sure where $\lambda$ has to tend to gain the possible result.

If $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\neq 0$ I would divide by $(-b)$ to obtain
$$\frac{-\sqrt{1-|a-\lambda b|^2}+\sqrt{1-|a|^2}}{-\lambda b} (-b)$$
to obtain
$$-\frac{ab}{\sqrt{1-|a|^2}}$$
as $\lambda\to 0$.
But I am not sure how to proceed in the case in which $a, b$ are vectors.

Could someone please help with that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking for in your question. As $\lambda \to 1$ don't you obtain the quantity $$\frac{b\left(-\sqrt{1-|a-b|^2}+\sqrt{1-|a|^2}\right)}{b}$$ What do you mean by dividing by the vector $b$ here?

Comment: @MATHBOI I apologize, I was editing the question in the meaning of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at it is as a projection of a gradient in a specific direction. In other words, there's a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and you're asking for $\nabla f \cdot b$.

If you were writing out a partial derivative by component, you'd have, for example:$$
\frac{f(x,y,z+h)-f(x,y,z)}{h}$$. But in vector notation, that's just:$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=D[f,\hat{\mathbf{k}}]=\frac{f(\vec{\mathbf{v}}+h \hat{\mathbf{k}})-f(\vec{\mathbf{v}})}{h}
$$
That works for any unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{u}}$ for a partial derivative in that direction. And, it works as you'd expect for non-unit vectors -- if you use $2\hat{\mathbf{k}}$, you get double the value.

Assuming some conditions hold on $f$, this is linear in the direction vector (there's some cases where this limit in every direction exists but the function isn't differentiable):
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\vec{\mathbf{v}}+h \vec{\mathbf{u}})-f(\vec{\mathbf{v}})}{h}=
D[f,\vec{\mathbf{u}}]\\
\begin{align}
&=D[f,u_x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+u_y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+u_z\hat{\mathbf{k}}]\\
&=u_x D[f,\hat{\mathbf{i}}] + u_y D[f,\hat{\mathbf{j}}] + u_z D[f,\hat{\mathbf{k}}]\\
&=u_x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+u_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+u_z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\\
&=\vec{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \nabla f
\end{align}
$$
So you should be able to apply that to $f(a)=\sqrt{1-\|a\|^2}$